# getting a error when running GPTNeoXForCausalLM from Transformers Library: NameError: name 'init_empty_weights' is not defined

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to run OpenAssistant's pythia-12b model but I'm getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'init_empty_weights' is not defined
```

I have Accelerate installed, and I'm running Transformers version 4.25.1

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, GPTNeoXForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
Model = "OpenAssistant/oasst-sft-1-pythia-12b"
    
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(Model, cache_dir='models_hf')
model = GPTNeoXForCausalLM.from_pretrained(Model, device_map="auto", load_in_8bit=True, cache_dir='models_hf',low_cpu_mem_usage=True)
    
message = "Hello, How are you?"
inp = "<|prompter|>"+message+"<|endoftext|><|assistant|>"
data = tokenizer([inp], return_tensors="pt")
data = {k: v.to(model.device) for k, v in data.items() if k in ("input_ids", "attention_mask")}
outputs = model.generate(**data)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]))
```

Comment: Upgrade `pip install -U transformers>=4.26.1`, also what machine are you running it on? Is it CPU or GPU? If GPU which cuda version?

Comment: I'm running it on a laptop CPU, on a Ryzen 5 3500U, I updated to 4.28.1 and it gave me a new error It seems I don't have enough ram to run the model, I'll try the 6B now, thanks!

Comment: Same problem with the `low_cpu_mem_usage` flag - can't update `transformers` because this version still isn't available in the conda repos

Answer (score 2):

In my case, installing accelerate package and re-starting the runtime was enough.
The same issue was also discussed [here](https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/issues/131).

Comment: Thanks, restarting my notebook kernel fixed it